# Koa.js serve React, api url also render with React page in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, koa

I'm using koa-static to serve static file with root url `localhost:3000/`, and koa-router to serve RESTful api, like `localhost:3000/api/account/login`

Make a `fakeBuild` folder contain only one file `index.html`. All work fine. root url and api url show correct content.

```
// serve static file
const serve = require('koa-static')
const staticPath = path.join(__dirname,'..','Client','poker','fakeBuild')
log(staticPath)
app.use(serve(staticPath))

// router
const router = require('./router/Index.js')(app)
```

Then I try to connect Koa with React

I use `yarn build` to build React static files, React project is created by `create-react-app`, not modified.

Then I change the koa-static's target to `build` folder, just one line changed

```
const staticPath = path.join(__dirname,'..','Client','poker','build')
```

Then access `localhost:3000/`, chrome show React start page, works

Then access `localhost:3000/api/account/login`, chrome show React start page, what??

Use postman check `localhost:3000/api/account/login`, it response what I put in router, fine.

So I can use apis, just ignore chrome's result?

It must be React and Chrome doing something extra. I try to remove `service-worker.js` in React build folder, api url render correctly in chrome.

So anyone can give some documents or explain to help me understand what react done, to keep all the url render it.

And why my api `localhost:3000/api/account/login` not require `service-worker.js` (just return some text in response body), also got the js worked. Just because `koa-static` served the file?

====

Update: my router code, And project available on [here](https://github.com/EzioKissshot/Koa-Demo-Project)

router/Index.js

```
const Router = require('koa-router');

const R = (app)=>{
  const router = new Router();


  const api = require('./Api.js');
  router.use('/api', api.routes(), api.allowedMethods())


  app.use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods());
};

module.exports = R;
```

router/Api.js

```
const Router = require('koa-router')
const log = require('../helper/Utils').log;

module.exports = (function () {
  const Api = new Router();
  Api.get('/account/login', async (ctx, next)=>{
    log("hello");
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = `login`
  });

  Api.get('/account/register', async (ctx, next)=>{
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = `register`

  });

  return Api;
})();
```

Comment: Update: I use another browser, open `/api/account/login` first, it show correctly. After open `/`, then open any apis, it show react page. So browser cached static file then react do something. Even if I disabled cache in chrome.

Comment: Can you please show how your router looks?

Comment: use router before static. thats how koa works.

Comment: @GProst I updated question, you can see whole project on github.

Comment: @ReiDien Tried to switch them, but no change.